# How to shorten the Url for tweet on tweeter

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I need to make an URL shorten for posting on tweeter using pro-grammatically .I find the Google API to shorten the url but in this API we need to register to get an API key.

Is there any other way to make an long URL to short URL using php.

Thanks in advance.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe, Twitter does it automatically when you tweet

Comment: actually I am using the YII framework and passing the controller function URL in twitter that URL render on view to show the content on tweeter.

Comment: [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-own-url-shortener/) tutorial should help you

Comment: _“but in this API we need to register to get an API key”_ – and what’s _wrong_ with that anyway …?

Answer (score 2):

Google API also has a method that doesn't require a key, you can access it via curl, eg:

```
$your_url = 'www.example.com/supermegalongurl.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('longUrl' => $your_url)));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$shorturl = json_decode($response)->id;

echo $shorturl; // http://goo.gl/b1rwpU
```

Answer (score 0):

Most API services will require you to register for a key bit.ly does as well.